# Count strings in a range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given N strings numbered 1 to N. We need to answer Q queries.

Each query is of the form **l r S**

For each query, we need to print the number of times the string S appears in the range [l,r].

Example :

Let N=3 and strings are  :

```
abc
def
abc
```

Say we have 3 queries :

**Query 1 : 1 2 abc**

Then answer is 1

**Query 2 : 1 3 abc**

Then answer is 2

**Query 3 : 1 2 hgj**

Then answer is 0

How to answer the queries in efficient way if both N and Q can be upto 100000 . Also Size of each string in the input is greater than or equal to 5 and less than or equal to 10.

Comment: why query 1's answer is 1? why not 2 for first and last strings? what am I missing?

Comment: Also, can we get query = `1 3 a`? do we need to look for a substring contains in the range? or an exact match?

Comment: @amit Exact match and for query 1 we need to check only string number 1 and 2

Comment: @amit for 1 3 a type query , answer will be zero

Comment: Got it, thought you were looking for substring and l r represent index in each string. thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a standard solution to this problem:

1. Let's have three types of events: a query starts, a query ends and a string appears. They should be processed in ascending order of their positions in the given array.
2. We will also maintain a map from a string to the number of its occurrences so far.
3. When we encounter the start event, we need to subtract the number of occurrences of the string that corresponds to the query from the answer.
4. When we see the end event, we need to add the number of occurrences of this string to the answer.
5. When a string appears, we just put it into the map.

The time complexity is `O((N + Q) log N)` if use a tree-based map implementation and `O(N + Q)` if we use a hash table.

Here is a C++ implementation of this solution:

```
struct Query {
    int left;
    int right;
    std::string str;

    Query(int left, int right, const std::string& str): 
        left(left), right(right), str(str) {}
};

// Returns the answers to the given queries. Queries' ranges
// must be 1-based.
std::vector<int> answerQueries(const std::vector<std::string>& s, 
        const std::vector<Query>& queries) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> startAt(s.size());
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> endAt(s.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++) {
        Query q = queries[i];
        startAt[q.left - 1].push_back(i);
        endAt[q.right - 1].push_back(i);
    }
    std::map<std::string, int> count;
    std::vector<int> res(queries.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        for (size_t q : startAt[i]) {
            res[q] -= count[queries[q].str];
        }
        count[s[i]]++;
        for (size_t q : endAt[i]) {
            res[q] += count[queries[q].str];
        }
    } 
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Why are you taking substrigs ? Whole strings need to be matched

Comment: @Mrinal I have misread the question. It is even easier this way.

Comment: @Mrinal Yes. I have slightly changed my answer. It should be fine now.

Comment: What are string_ids here ??

Comment: @Mrinal The result of mapping all strings to numbers.

Comment: No idea about your solution ..:(.. Whats its complexity ?And can you explain it with some example ?

Comment: @Mrinal The time complexity is `O(n + q)` or `O((n  + q) log n)`(it depends on whether we use a hash table or a tree map). I'll add an example soon.

Comment: By mapping strings you mean "abc" -> 0 , "def" ->1  , "abc" -> 2  ?

Comment: @Mrinal The same strings must be mapped to the same number. So its abc->0, def -> 1, abc -> 0.

Comment: What abot strings that are not present in input strings and are present in queries ? Like in my example

Comment: @Mrinal We map all strings initially.

Comment: @ kraskevich Whats list[n] here ?

Comment: @Mrinal An array of empty lists.

Comment: Whats space complexity for this solution ? I doubt its O(N*Q)

Comment: @Mrinal It is linear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73987/discussion-between-mrinal-and-kraskevich).

Answer (score 0):

1. For given strings create a map string -> sorted positions in input
2. For each query use 2 binary searches for l and r in sorted positions to find the number of occurrences in range

Comment: Had you got the question ?

Comment: Well, If we need to match whole strings as you said, this approach should work. To find the number of times S appear in range just subtract positions p1 - p2, where p1 = map[S].binary_search(l) and p2 = map[S].binary_search(r). Space complexity O(N), time complexity O(Q*log(N))

Comment: @mechatroner How you will do For given strings create a map string -> sorted positions in input ??

Comment: @Mrinal   in Python:     `pss = dict()  
    for p, ln in enumerate(sys.stdin):  
        ln = ln.rstrip('\n')  
        if (ln not in pss):  
            pss[ln] = list()  
        pss[ln].append(p)  `